# Handle Universal links with react native on iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, ios-universal-links

I'm implementing universal links for react native.

I followed this instructions : https://reactnavigation.org/docs/deep-linking/ and for android it's works well.
When i trying to do for iOS (Associated Domains i have some issues)

For this i followed this instructions : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/supporting-associated-domains?language=objc

1. Create Associated Domain on xCode
2. Create apple-app-site-association on .well-known folder (https://dev-bytel-suiviconso.azurewebsites.net/.well-known/apple-app-site-association)

```
  "applinks": {
    "details": [
      {
        "appIDs": [
          "ABCDE12345.com.example.app",
          "ABCDE12345.com.example.app2"
        ],
        "components": [
          {
            "#": "no_universal_links",
            "exclude": true,
            "comment": "Matches any URL with a fragment that equals no_universal_links and instructs the system not to open it as a universal link."
          },
          {
            "/": "/buy/*",
            "comment": "Matches any URL with a path that starts with /buy/."
          },
          {
            "/": "/help/website/*",
            "exclude": true,
            "comment": "Matches any URL with a path that starts with /help/website/ and instructs the system not to open it as a universal link."
          },
          {
            "/": "/help/*",
            "?": {
              "articleNumber": "????"
            },
            "comment": "Matches any URL with a path that starts with /help/ and that has a query item with name 'articleNumber' and a value of exactly four characters."
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "webcredentials": {
    "apps": [
      "ABCDE12345.com.example.app"
    ]
  },
  "appclips": {
    "apps": [
      "ABCED12345.com.example.MyApp.Clip"
    ]
  }
}
```

4. I checked my files is correct on this sites

- https://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator/#resultsbox
- https://search.developer.apple.com/appsearch-validation-tool

[image]

- https://app-site-association.cdn-apple.com/a/v1/dev-bytel-suiviconso.azurewebsites.net

but when i'm checking for ubereats.com or facebook
https://app-site-association.cdn-apple.com/a/v1/ubereats.com

the format for apple-app-site-association is different, they are using format defined here : https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016308-CH12-SW1

```
{
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [
            {
                "appID": "9JA89QQLNQ.com.apple.wwdc",
                "paths": [ "/wwdc/news/", "/videos/wwdc/2015/*"]
            },
            {
                "appID": "ABCD1234.com.apple.wwdc",
                "paths": [ "*" ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

[image: open scheme]

So which format i should use or where i have wrong ?

It's finally work on simulator but not on real device

[image: simulator]

Comment: How do you test the deep links?
e.g. ```npx uri-scheme open "9JA89QQLNQ.com.apple.wwdc/--/buy" --ios```

Comment: For testing i used safari on the uri but i'm not redirected.

Actually i'm blocked to "The entitlement data used to verify deep link dual authentication is from the current released version of your app. This data may take 48 hours to update."

I don't know if i have to push the app on apple store or betaflight to be approved

Comment: But does it work locally ?

Comment: It's doesn't work locally.

But if i run `npx uri-schema open "myconsobytel://xxx"` it's work's


What i whave on schema are :  `npx uri-scheme list

› iOS: Schemes for config: ./ios/SuiviConso/Info.plist
› myconsobytel://

› Android: Schemes for config: ./android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
› myconsobytel://
› http://
› https://
`

Answer (score 2):

iOS will not open Universal Links with apps if the user types the url directly into the browser. Only when the user clicks a link, will iOS open the associated app.

So, in order to test the setup, do not enter the link in Safari, but rather use:

```
npx uri-scheme open "https://your-site/testpath" --ios
```

Alternatively, create a reminder on the device (using the Reminders app) containing the link, and click it.

Comment: "iOS will not open Universal Links with apps if the user types the url directly into the browser." 

Helped a lot, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based on the format that is being used by sites like UberEats and Facebook, you should use the format defined in the Universal Links documentation by Apple.

The format should look like this:

```
{
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [
            {
                "appID": "your.bundle.id",
                "paths": [ "your_desired_path/*"]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The appID key should contain your bundle ID, and the paths key should specify the desired path of your Universal Link. The apps key should be empty.

If it's not working on a real device, check if you have enabled Associated Domains on Xcode, and if you have the correct Bundle ID set in your Apple Developer account. It's also important to check if the

> apple-app-site-association

file is hosted on a secure server (HTTPS) and is accessible to your device.